# Как вывести по Н позиций из каждой компании из списка?

Tags: python, json, pandas

[image: таблица pandas где хранится информация по фирмам разным. по 420 данных на каждую фирму. Не могу отобрать по 20 данных из каждой фирмы чтоб переформировать таблицу]

таблица pandas, где хранится информация по фирмам разным. по 420 данных на каждую фирму. Не могу отобрать по 20 первых строк для каждой фирмы, чтобы переформировать таблицу

```
import pandas as pd
stockQuotes = pd.read_json (r'D:\NeuroNet\DataBase\TimeSeriesPD.json')
stockQuotes = stockQuotes \
    .rename(columns = {0: 'Company', 1: 'DataTime', 2: 'Price'})
stockQuotesCAT = stockQuotes.loc[stockQuotes.Company == 'CAT'].reset_index()
del stockQuotesCAT['index'] 
stockQuotesCAT.to_json('TimeSeriesCatPD.json')
stockQuotesNoCAT = stockQuotes.loc[stockQuotes.Company != 
'CAT'].reset_index()
del stockQuotesNoCAT['index'] 
stockQuotesNoCAT.to_json('TimeSeriesNoCatPD.json')
```

Comment: Мне кажется я буквально вчера видел вопрос с таким же скриншотом, но не могу теперь найти его

Comment: Удалил. попросили добавить код. правда незнаю чем поможет этот код. я открыл json файл. отделил одну фирму из общего списка. и из оставшегося списке мне надо составить новую таблицу по 20данных отобрав с каждой компании. и не могу какой функцией в пандас то сделать. (именно работая с таблицами pandas/ через циклы все в питоне то можно отобрать. а тут работаю в этом пакете)

Comment: данные уже сгруппированы по компаниям и времени) я их так и достал через api и записал в json файл. потом начал работать с библиотекой пандас. и вот весь код что написал в файле отдельном преобразуя файл json в pandas формат

Comment: Вас просили не код добавить, а данные.

Comment: что значит "20 данных"? 20 первых строк? 20 любых?

Comment: кто знает как это сделаить, знает эту функцию, тому данные не нужны. мне просто нужен вид функции. ответил же кто знал)

Comment: данные нужны, чтобы показать вам пример. вам задали вопрос, причем в ответе его повторили - что значит "20 данных"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как-то так должно получиться с использованием группировки и кумулятивного счётчика:

```
stockQuotes.loc[stockQuotes.groupby('Company').cumcount() < 20]
```

Если вам нужно не просто по 20 первых записей от каждой компании, а с учётом какой-то сортировки (например, по дате) - отсортируйте предварительно ваш DataFrame нужным образом.

Comment: Благодарю)) данные уже отсортированны)) просто надо было первые 20 записей от каждой компании достать. а так они отсортированы по компаниям и датам)